# Make Postman test - Grails

Tags: rest, http, post, grails, postman

I have the following test of a grails integration:

```
def http = new HTTPBuilder(loginUrl)
http.request( POST, TEXT ) {
    headers.'User-Agent' = 'Mozilla/5.0 Ubuntu/8.10 Firefox/3.0.4'
    send URLENC, [j_username: username, j_password: password]

    response.success = { resp, reader ->
        loggedIn = ! reader.text.contains("j_username")
    }
}
```

I'm trying to mount the test in Postman, but I'm not sure if I'm doing it correctly because of this `send URLENC, [j_username: username, j_password: password]`

I put the POST type route, and put something like:

```
{
    j_username: username,
    j_password: password
}
```

And the headers parameters:

```
'User-Agent' = 'Mozilla/5.0 Ubuntu/8.10 Firefox/3.0.4'
'Content-type' = 'Application/json'
```

But it is always returning my login form in the body, does anyone know how to mount this test?

**UPDATE**

Actually in other projects I follow the reference and it works well. However I have developed the grails response part, did not leave an `api/login` route, and I believe that the login is done by the same web route `/login/auth`, but I can not validate the test by postman, but on the web logo perfectly.

**UPDATE 2**

I believe that in the project that receives my login request, to try to facilitate, they have made access to the api by the same web, and this request that is mounted in the integration, do not make a json type request, because of "send URLENC", Can someone please explain to me how to put this call in postman?

Comment: You should be using the `x-www-form-urlencoded` option for this. With `j_username` and `j_password` as the field names

Answer (score -1):

If you have the default Spring Security and Spring Security REST config, here how I do it :

[image: Body of the Postman call]

[image: Header of the Postman call]

Comment: That's exactly how I tried it, too. But what you put in the header was only the ´application/json´?

Comment: Yes. Have you configured the filter chains as specified in: http://alvarosanchez.github.io/grails-spring-security-rest/latest/docs/#_plugin_configuration

Comment: Actually in other projects I follow the reference and it works well. However I have developed the grails response part, did not leave an api / login route, and I believe that the login is done by the same web route, / login / auth, but I can not validate the test by postman, but on the web logo perfectly.

Comment: The way Spring Security REST does REST login is via a special interceptor that catches calls to /api/login. It's not using the LoginController like the web login form does. So proper configuration as specified in the documentation is required.

Comment: So, the route when taking /api/login, it returns me 401 and does not find. So I'm trying to login through Postman like I'm using the login form.

Comment: @ 
bassmartin [ink](alvarosanchez.github.io/grails-spring-security-rest/latest/docs/…) seems not working